# store and retrieve image from WAMP server using android

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, wampserver

I have one android application where admin user can create normal user account in which admin user can select photo of normal user to create account. Things are working great till i am storing normal user name,Age ETC. But problem arises when i want to store image of normal user to database.
I am using Wamp server as back end database.

Can you guys please suggest me how to store image in WAMP server as well as how to retrieve it again so that i can display on android activity.

Functionality is like,
Admin User login ----> Create Normal User --> Select Image --> Store in database.

Normal user login --->Retrieve image from Database --> View image in Android activity.

Comment: How are you going about storing images in the database? If you want the images loaded to be on the device and not somewhere on the internet, it could be on an internal or external storage. Then the value can just be the path/url of the image source. You might want to check out [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to get started.

Comment: @VivekPradhan you are not getting my point man, We can store image on WAMP server you may found the related tutorials on internet. I just want to link WAMP server to android. That is simply, Storing image into WAMP and retrieve it again

Comment: You need to clairify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are trying to store images in a database and a normal user can see them. I think your problem is how to store images in the database, right? If I'm correct you can store image names instead of imagse like you would store age and name.

For example you can create a folder called *images* then you store all the images in this folder. When you want retrieve an image you can get the url/a link pointing to the image.

For example when an admin stores an image named "image1.jpg" you can program to store the picture to the image folder and also set the name in your database, then this image has a specific id and a url and when a normal user wants to retrieve the image you should instruct your code to get the id and then the respective url which are stored in your database as a string.

For a reliable handling you can create folders like `image_jpg` `image_png`, `image_gif` and so on. Then progmatically check the image type when the admin uploads photos and store them in the correct folder according to the type. And also you can store `id`, `type` and `name` in your database then check the type and create the full path url according to these parameters when you present them to the user

```
.....................

id   | type |name

0001 | jpg  |image1

0002 | gif  |image2

.....................
```

When a normal user wants to see an image all you need is the image name and the path/url. In this example the image url for

```
0001 is   "path/image_jpg/image1."+type
0002 is   "path/image_gif/image2."+type
```

When you know the id you can get the type then it's easy to create the path or url for your image...

Comment: Agree!! Are you talking about storing image file on WAMP server directory. And path of image will store in Database..

Comment: Ok, is there any way to store actual image in database.

Comment: what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472233/can-i-store-images-in-mysql?

Comment: yes you can store image as base64 string in database and that should be in raw type

Answer (score 4):

Another way of storing image in server is using webservice. do as follow:

**Server Side**

A. Accept image from client device

```
 1. create webservice to accept image as base64 string.
 2. convert base64 to image and store on server directory.
 3. save the path of image in DB.
```

B. Send image to client devices.

```
 1. create webservice to send image to client device
 2. retrieve image path from DB.
 3. generate Image URL and sent it as response to client device
```

**Client Device** android

A. send Image to server

```
 1. convert image to base64 String.
 2. call webservice to send image as base64 String.
```

B. Retrive Image

```
 1. call webservice to retrieve image URL.(Best way to get image is using lazzy loading)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using simple form http post to create details in wamp server. But if you want to upload images/file then you will have to use multipart request.

If you are saving the image as binary in db, then during retrieval 
 1. Send it down as a stream, esentially the client will have to download the image and show it as required.
 2. Generate the image and save it on your server and send back a url which the client can use to retrieve image.

Answer (score 0):

create database
create table  with image attribute (write data type of image is blob)
insert into table_name values(load_file('location of image where image is stored'))
then do and open image