# How to cache base64 encode image

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, image, base64

Hi I am developing small school app  using **angular.js** and **php** that captures images from canvas and then stores  it in **mySql** db.

The images are stored `image/png`;`base64 string`.

My problem is that when I load these images (300 images of 11.2Kb) it takes lot of time to display it on screen (**approx 1 minute for 3Mb HTML**).

Are there any libraries or angular directives that I can use to cache these images when displaying?

Comment: You can use PHP Cache Engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, first of all, storing images in the DB is [quite a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472268/2044039). I would recommend you to save images as binary files and store the upload paths.

Second, storing large images in base64 would take more memory (base64 images are usually ~33% larger than binaries), and, as [claimed here](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/), rendering them might take a significantly more time.

> base64 encoded data may possibly take longer to process than binary
>   data  (again, this might be exceptionally painful for mobile devices,
>   which have more limited CPU and memory)

BTW if I misunderstood you and the bottleneck is reading images from the db, then storing images as files would also help ;)