# Store multiple images

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Hello how can i upload multiple images to my table, for now i have this table

```
Schema::create('articles', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('title', 70);
            $table->string('slug', 100)->unique();
            $table->string('images');
            $table->text('content');
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->timestamps();
           $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

i want to store multiple images in "images" field, how could i do that ?

Comment: What is the schema of "images" table. Did you mean "images" field?

Comment: yes i mean field, Thks its corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store the images data directly in a database column, it's not the best practice at all. Read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6472268/830130

Differently if you want to do the right way in my opinion it's better to delete that string column you called "images" and create an images table, with a foreign key referencing the id on articles.

In Laravel the relation can be done using the Eloquent relationships.

In your case you can decide to have a one-to-many: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

or a many-to-many relationship: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: well i actualy want to store the image path.. i will create a images table like you mentioned, thank you