# Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, image, file

I get this error everytime i hit the submit button. Everything else is submitted to the database, only the image isn't. 
Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty
Any idea? Here is my code.

```
if(isset($_POST['consultationbutton'])){        
    $image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['selectedfile']['tmp_name'])); //SQL Injection defence!
    $image_name = addslashes($_FILES['selectedfile']['name']);
    $checkedcondition = implode(",",$_POST['skincondition']);
    $checkedproduct = implode(",",$_POST['skincareinuse']);
    $consultquery="INSERT INTO counsel(nric,dateconsulted,editableface,skincarecurrentlyinuse,skincondition,imagename) VALUES('132','$_POST[storedate]','{$image}','$checkedproduct','$checkedcondition','{$image_name}')";
    mysqli_query($dbconn,$consultquery);
   // mysqli_escape_string($dbconn,$image);
    echo $checkedcondition;
    echo $checkedproduct;
}   

<form action="BAConsult.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>
<img id="customerface" src="#" alt="your image" class ="consultimg"></img>
 Select a file to upload: <input type="file" name="selectedfile" onchange="readURL(this);">
<input type='submit' name='consultationbutton' class='consultationbutton' value='Complete Consultation' onclick='submitclick();'>
</form>

<script>
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#customerface')
                .attr('src', e.target.result)
                .width(400)
                .height(400);
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is the value of `$_FILES['selectedfile']['tmp_name']`?

Comment: Read this for uploading file: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: @Alok I can upload the file up already, the problem is sending it to the database

Comment: @castis i got [name]=>DSC_0770.JPG[type]=> [tmp_name]=>[error]=>1[size]=>0 , it looks like the tmp_name is the problem i think

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `$_FILES` array, you've said you're getting `[name]=>DSC_0770.JPG[type]=> [tmp_name]=>[error]=>1[size]=>0`

If `tmp_name` is not given, that means the file was not uploaded.

The error you're given is `1`, and according to the [upload error messages explained page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) this means: that the uploaded file exceeds the [upload_max_filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) directive in php.ini.

You can do the following to fix this.

- Find your php.ini file and increase the size of `upload_max_filesize`.
- Use `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');` or whatever size you want at the start of your script.
- Compress your images before uploading.

Comment: Ahh i see, is there a way to increase the max upload file size?

Comment: okay great im getting 0 error but now my SQL queries are having problems, it says MySQL Server has gone away

Comment: That is a different problem altogether. That could happen if you're trying to store a giant image in the server. You probably dont want to store whole images in mysql.

Comment: OMG it worked! It really is because my image is too big. Somehow, when i changed my max upload size, my sql database wasn't able to handle it even if my program is able to. Thank you very much :)

Comment: You're welcome! Also check out the first answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472233/can-i-store-images-in-mysql) for some info on storing images in a sql server.

Answer (score 3):

make sure you add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `<form>` tag. like

```
<form action="your_action_file" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: are you using two input file in your page? can you post your full code here. So it will be easy for us to rectify your issue

Comment: Okay, you can check it out now.. the other html codes are just checkboxes so i will not post them up

Comment: Its the code i posted, action="BAConsult.php" just brings it back to the same page on submit

Comment: are you submitting the form without selecting the file

Comment: I've selected the file already but it seems like the file is too big, im trying to expand the max upload limit now

Comment: I tried in my local server its working fine unless if you select the file it shows the error

Comment: The problem is resolved, it turns out that it was my image size which was too large! Thanks :)

Comment: Good luck buddy... keep developing

Comment: thanks....you are really a lifesaver...I was forgetting to put enctype on form action