# How to store parsed images from Zapier into MySQL directory?

Tags: mysql, parsing, storage, zapier

I'm done with parsing email using Zapier but storing parsed data(Image) in MySQL is not something I'm familiar with. I've stored images in DB table but its not viewable. Could someone experienced please help with how I can store images coming from Zapier parsed email to SQL directory.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I store images in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472233/can-i-store-images-in-mysql)