# store image locally and refrence them in react app

Tags: mysql, reactjs

I'm building a desktop app with React and MySQL, I only store the image name in MySQL and the actual images are in the images folder in `/src/images`, When uploading new images to the images folder, the react app reload, So to avoid that from happening

1. I either need to store the images in MySQL DB
2. access the images locally not in /src but outside like `D:/images/*`.

but react has some importing restrictions.

How can I resolve this issue, please share your knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [import and use images directly in the component](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files) or serve your images as publically available static assets.

You can do this in plenty of ways:

1. [Put all images in React's `/public/images` directory](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder) making them static assets of your page
2. Serve images as static assets from your backend ([here how to do it in express.js](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html))
3. Serve images as static assets from 3rd party storage service (e.g.: [Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/quickstart-blobs-javascript-browser))
4. [Store images in database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6472233/1330105) and provide them to frontend as data blobs - while it is possible, it's not recommended.

Comment: But my images folder is not static its dynamic ,I'm adding new images to it while the front end is open.

Comment: So go with 2nd, 3rd or 4th option.