# Matrix Like Data (2d array) into SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

How should I store the data in the screenshot in a MySQL table?  It's pretty much a matrix or a 2d Array.  Just looking for the exact SQL statement(s) to use to store and retrieve this data and what that should look like on the database side.

```
         1          2         3
Liner    6          6         6
Rod      0          0         0
Stk      8.5        9.5       12
Eff      95         98        97
Stroke   0          0         59
Disp     0.0706     0.0709    0.0997
```

```
-- How to do a 2D array like this on the database side?
-- 1
-- 2
-- 3
-- 4
-- All columns from 2D array:
CREATE TABLE DAILY_MUD_REPORT (
liner  INT,
rod INT,
stk DECIMAL(25, 4),
eff INT,
stroke INT,
disp DECIMAL(25, 4));
```

My initial thoughts are just to store each row as a column.  Is that how to do this?  I am just trying to figure out how to store this in a MySQL database.

Comment: How did you try to store this info? Did you try anything ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I store images in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6472233/can-i-store-images-in-mysql)

Comment: I'm not looking to store the image of the data.  I am looking to store the data itself from this format into SQL tables.

Comment: Never post screenshots of your data here. Confusion like this is only one of several failure modes. _formatted text_ will give you much better results. Images will just get you downvotes and a question that is closed or ignored.